# Alternative expression/phrase to the expression "mushroom growth"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

In Indian English, the expression **mushroom growth** is quite common, some sample constructions

> There has been **a mushroom growth** in organic fruits shops in this area.

> Advancements in the telecommunications industry explain **the mushroom growth** in the streaming providers in India.

I have never heard this phrase in American English. Could somebody please suggest an alternative phrase/or alternative sentence construction, which would convey the same meaning.

Population explosion would fit, but it sounds very awkward to my ears.

Comment: Not unknown. Did you do a web search? "The mushroom growth in popularity for online video platforms like Vine and YouTube have proven consumers are in love with video." - Artisan.com (an American company).

Comment: "mushroom growth in organic fruit" sounds like something completely different.

Answer (score 3):

The terms *exponential growth* and *explosive growth* would be more common, at least in American English.  The term *mushroom growth* would be readily understood, but you would never expect to hear it used here.

Comment: That's right, but you do get the verb "mushrooming" used sometimes  "Costs are mushrooming and we need to make savings"

Answer (score 0):

I did a little more research after posting the question, I think the word "rise" fits my requirements.

Comment: That fits, but is probably less dramatic than "mushroom growth." You might also consider "boom": https://www.investopedia.com/terms/b/boom.asp#:~:text=A%20boom%20refers%20to%20a,marked%20by%20significant%20GDP%20growth.